# Multiprocessing pool for loop in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code used to calculate statistics from my simulation. I want to use a multiprocessing pool (similar to parfor in Matlab). Below is my code. I have n-th data points and I want to distribute these data points to nCPUs to calculate the result.

In def process_data(pts), it begins from ii_start < ii < ii_end. I have a line to implement the loop,

```
results = pool.map(process_data, range(ii_start, ii_end + 1))
```

In Matlab, I simply use

```
parfor ii = ii_start:ii_end
```

Do I need to have something similar in python?
Also, my confusion is, e.g pts = 98, it will direct to tmean[98] do perform the calculation and I then obtain ea[98], however, I am not sure how to obtain the index from ii_start:ii_end and apply that to process_data.

The script begins here.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import os
import h5py

filepath = '/actual_file_path/rry.mat'
rry_data = {}
f = h5py.File(filepath)
for k, v in f.items():
    rry_data[k] = np.array(v)

C_sorted        = rry_data['C_sorted'].T
ea              = rry_data['ea'].T
idxnew          = rry_data['idxnew'].T
ii              = rry_data['ii'].T        # prev stop point
ny              = rry_data['ny'].T
rhostarprofile  = rry_data['rhostarprofile'].T
rry             = rry_data['rry'].T
tmean           = rry_data['tmean'].T
ymean           = rry_data['ymean'].T
Ystar           = rry_data['Ystar'].T


n = len(ea)

saveInterval = int(1e6)
saveFilename = '/actual_file_path/ea_temp'

ii_start = 98
ii_end = 110.   # setting 110 for testing, ii_end = 172439820
pts = np.linspace(1,n,n)
# Initialize a global list to store results
all_results = []


def process_data(pts):
    
    rho = tmean[pts]  # Python uses 0-based indexing
    rystar = int(idxnew[pts])
    sortedrhoheight = Ystar[rystar]   

    mod = int((pts-1)%ny)
    ry = int(rry[mod])
    rhoheight = Ystar[ry]  

    if sortedrhoheight > rhoheight:
        rhobar = (1 / (rhoheight - sortedrhoheight)) * -1 * np.sum(rhostarprofile[ry:rystar, 0] * C_sorted[ry:rystar, 1])
    elif sortedrhoheight == rhoheight:
        rhobar = 0
    else:
        rhobar = (1 / (rhoheight - sortedrhoheight)) * np.sum(rhostarprofile[rystar:ry, 0] * C_sorted[rystar:ry, 1])

    ea[pts] = (rhoheight - sortedrhoheight) * (rho - rhobar)

# number of cores you have allocated for your slurm task:
number_of_cores = int(os.environ['SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK'])
print(number_of_cores)
# number_of_cores = cpu_count() # if not on the cluster you should do this instead

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Parallel loop for ii_start to ii_end
#    with Pool(processes=int(os.environ['SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK'])) as pool:
    with Pool(number_of_cores) as pool:
        pool.map(process_data, range(ii_start, ii_end + 1))
```

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is (I think there's a typo in your question). Also, code like *rho = tmean[ii]* in process_data() is highly dubious. I have no idea why you're returning ii from process_data()

Comment: Hi there, thank for your reply. I am still new to python so I am not sure if I am doing the right thing. What I am trying to do is allocate nCPUS to calculate ea and that will be 172439820 data points. If I do it in serial, it will take a long time. Hence, I want to implement multiprocessing pool to speed up the calculation. I have edited my code slightly, it will be good if you can take a look again. Thanks

Comment: *rho = tmean[pts]* is still dubious. The values passed to process_data() should depend on the size of objects such as *tmean*

Comment: Do you mean something like len(tmean)?

Comment: Do you already have code which works sequentially? Can you write it? That would make it much easier for others to help you with making it parallel.

Comment: Hi @pts, The code above is working fine. I have tried to print out the values of pts and ea[pts] and it does begin from ii_start and ii_end. Another problem is how to save the ea that corresponds to pts which is the index of the array. Thanks

Comment: If your code is working fine 100%, then what do you want to learn from the answers? Please clarify what you are asking.